5 minute cartoon before main show started - Channel 4 UK - Early 90's
It should be noted that the time frame and channel are up for grabs as far as accuracy goes.
Sometime between 92 and 96, Channel 4 in the UK used to have these shorts(?) they would sometimes air after a show finished and before the next one started. So if the previous show finished at 14:50, they would have 5 minutes of ads, then this short would play, then the next main show would start at 15:00.
One of the shorts was a cartoon series that involved a man whose head was made out of stacks of paper. He was the only character as far as I can remember, and he kind of looked like the 7-up guy as his hair was formed out of the stacks of paper falling forward at the top. The backdrop was always a static picture of a file room or similar in blue shades, with a desk. He wore a bright yellow suit.
As far as a synopsis goes, all I can remember was that he worked as a newspaper reporter or something similar, and each 5-minute episode would just be him talking to the camera, some jokes, and a few cut scenes(but I don't remember what these were).
There was no set time these were on, they were just randomly before shows started. It looks like the show I am looking for was part of the 'Four-Mation' shorts shown on Channel 4 in the 90's.
Below is my rough sketch of what it looked like from my extremely dodgy memory.

Does anyone recognise this show?

That was in the days when Channel 4 was failing to sell all its advertising time.  Fill-in shorts were shown and were often different on different transmitters as some advertising was regional.

@Chenmunka Interesting, wasn't aware of that.

@superphonic - I found a list of 'Four-Mation' episodes here but haven't had a chance to search through them yet to see if one of those is what you saw: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHk7Mi8CK44gLUKzEiiDWmzUztGd6AzPZ.

@tohood87 Excellent! A quick look through them and I can't see anything that looks right, but I'll spend some more time going through.

I still haven't found this cartoon. Look like it was probably a Four-Mation, but haven't come across it yet. Bounty added!

I and a bunch of people I knew worked on Four mations in that era. I'll have a look. Most of my stuff is in storage or thrown out though, so no guarantees.

With a hat tip to blobbymcblobby for their excellent find, the character you've depicted is Monsieur Lulo.

He was the animated host of a TV show called Télétoon which aired on Fr3 (in France) and Channel 4 in the UK during the early 1990s, showcasing French-produced low-budget animation.

Télétoon was [] the name of a 41-episode documentary show devoted to
animated cinema, produced by France 3 and Channel 4. Broadcast in 1990
and 1991. Its presenter was a cartoon character called Lulo.

You would have seen it on Channel 4 around 5pm for a few months in 1992

Yeah, so the Four mations were more like bumpers (bit like the Channel 4 logo competition bumpers), Teletoon was rather more developed than those were.

Thanks! This is the one!!!

Not entirely an answer but might jog the memory:
I and people I know (some who are still alive) worked on some of the four mations jobs in the 90s - some got aired, lots did not, some got redirected to other channels after some changes (MTV, VH1, etc).
Your image sample though, comes up as something entirely different, and I do recall it:


a french animated character used on the channel France 3

https://www.studioghibli.fr/reportage-de-fr3-sur-hayao-miyazaki-diffuse-en-1992/
Note, looks like it was connected to the airing of studio ghibli movies in france at the time. He might have been ported lock, stock and barrel with the said studio ghibli shows to the uk (as a package) and aired that way, so not actually a uk originating product.
Note: thats an incredibly accurate sketch from memory!
edit:
there you go.
visit http://esmma.free.fr/mde4/teletoon.htm for more!

The Ghibli stuff is from C'est Lulo, which broadcast in France and showcased world animated cinema, but didn't air in the UK. Right character, wrong show.

yeah, so interesting, Teletoon got a broadcast slot in the UK. It didnt seem like it could be a Four mations piece by itself. Being in the trade you were looking at all sort of stuff in the day. Never got to Annecy myself though.

Oh Wow! This is the one. Amazing stuff. I never thought I would find out what this was. I was 11 or 12 at the time and big in to drawing cartoons and comics. I'd copy all sorts of cartoons and this one stuck with me throughout the years but I could never find where it came from. Thank you!!

@superphonic Hi there! I think Valorum should get the acceptance - I only had a hint, but they got the correct character name and tv show first in their answer :) Though as I say, you had such an accurate sketch to work from, well done!

Appreciate it. I have accepted @Valorum answer now.

This is a long shot, but your illustration reminds me of a Saturday morning kids show that aired on ITV between 1995 and 1998 called "Scratchy & Co.".
Starring Mark Speight as "Scratchy", the show featured various skits and jokes that filled time between a regular set of cartoons and other kids shows.
Based on your description this is most likely not what you are referring to, but at least we can rule it out.


Thanks for the answer. This isn't what I am looking for, but I do remember this show though :-)
